# IIS looking bootstrap fonts under wrong location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application. The application has `fonts` folder at its root location. (It was created by default by VS 2017 when you create new application)
[image]

When i run application locally in visual studio everything works fine. But when i deploy it to IIS and browse any page where `glyphicons` been used, i see error below (in Fiddler)

[image]

I don't know why the path is changed? instead of looking font under `/fonts` folder it is looking under `/Content/fonts` folder.

Comment: Are you using bundling when you deploy?  If so, your bundle path could be mucking your CSS paths as they are relative.  If you pass the `CssRewriteUrlTransform()` function to your bundle, it should rewrite the URLs so that they still point to the correct location such as `new StyleBundle("~/Css/Site").Include("~/Content/PickDateThemes/default.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())`

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that paths in a CSS file are relative, using the built-it bundling mechanism could be causing your paths to resolve to an incorrect location.  In order to resolve this issue, you can pass an additional parameter to each of your CSS files in your bundle that will rewrite the paths in the compressed CSS so that it still ultimately points to the correct paths for your files such as images and fonts.

Example (from one of my current projects)

```
var siteCss = new StyleBundle("~/Css/Site")
           .Include("~/Content/PickDateThemes/default.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
           .Include("~/Content/PickDateThemes/default.date.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
           .Include("~/Content/PickDateThemes/default.time.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
           .Include("~/Content/app.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
           .Include("~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.foundation.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```